# Phonegap Android JQuery Mobile not firing backbutton event

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use the event backbutton following this reference: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

But the event is not triggered and all other events (resume, pause, etc.) are working.

But if I remove the jQuery Mobile library, the event is triggered as documented above.

Anyone have experienced this behavior using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile together?

```
// add events after deviceready invoked
document.addEventListener('resume', function(){
    console.log('event - invoked resume');
}, false);
document.addEventListener('pause', function(){
    console.log('event - invoked pause');
}, false);
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(){
    console.log('event - invoked backbutton');
}, false);
```

Comment: Although it seems trivial, you should post your code. There may actually be a typo or some unseen bug that is the real issue.

Comment: This is not the error - but you have an extra comma in your `document.addEventListener('resume'...` call.

Comment: Thanks, it was the time to paste here. But unfortunately it is the error: (